# Pixel Color does not always appear the same

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, pixel, texture2d

I have a falling sand style game that is currently only using two colors, black and cyan. I am setting the colors of a texture using `texture.SetData<Color>(colorArray);`

The main program updates the colors, when a pixel leaves a spot, the color at that position is set to black, and the new spot is set to cyan. However, as you can see in the picture, the cyan color is not uniform through out (look closely at the bottom right, it is very dark blue). This is occurring on a windows phone emulator. At first I thought the screen might just be updating so fast that the colors are projecting and leaving to quickly, but after stopping the update method (to take the following picture) the colors remained the same.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

There is no shading (unless it is being done automatically and I don't realize it). There is only: `colorArray[position] = Black;` and `colorArray[newPos] = Cyan;`

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SfJweTg.png]

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        map.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, fps, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    //map.Draw()
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb)
    {
        sb.Draw(pixels, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    }

    public void Update()
    { 
          //this is only a portion of the update method
          colors[currentpos] = getColor(0);// returns a color from a list
          //some more updates not related to the texture
          //blah
          //blah blah
          colors[currentpos] = getColor(ID);// returns a color from a list
          //at the end of the update loop
          texture.SetData<Color>(colors);              
    }
```

Comment: There must be some shading going on. If you look everything that isn't black is a shade of cyan. I don't really understand why you are using textures to display what are effectively pixels though.

Comment: How would I display a pixel then? Because I have been looking for a faster way to do that too... As for the shading, I have not changed anything about the spritebatch or graphics device. Where else could it be occurring?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with xna but you should be able to set a colour or material on your objects.

Comment: Interpolation would cause this - my guess is that the window is being stretched or shrunk somehow.  Make sure the display-buffer is the exact size it's actually being displayed at.

Comment: Oh haha, there really is no other way (in XNA) to manipulate pixels that I have found effective. But thats besides the point. :p

Comment: Hmm. I am only drawing the texture with sprite batch to the screen. And the size of the texture is set to the size of the viewport at initialization. Where else could a stretch occur?

Comment: if your gamplay area is set to 800x600 and your window is resizable so you resize it then could result with artefacts. actualy what BlueRaja said.

Comment: Well the game play area is just the view port of a windows phone, which is not resizable. The windows width/height is 800/480, and the texture is 800/480. So, I understand that you guys could have the right answer, I just don't know where to look to see if anything else is somehow changing behind the scenes. Any hints?

Comment: That's extremely important information that should have been mentioned in the question; I would edit that into the question (including -- most importantly -- code), or better yet, delete this and repost with the new info -- including code -- and proper tags (windows-phone, etc.) since otherwise you are unlikely to get many more views.  Did I mention include some code?

Comment: If there were any more code to post, I would have posted it. I explained what there is and what there isn't, not everything needs code to be solved. I already said the code doesn't do anything crazy, there is only the most basic of draw calls.

Comment: ...This one **does** need code to be solved *(and in fact, if it didn't, it wouldn't be a good fit for this site)*.  Please post it so we can help you.

Comment: If the code shown helps I'll eat a shoe.

Comment: Check the WPE's zoom level http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402566(v=vs.105).aspx it looks as though (from the image posted) that it's been downscaled, and the colours have been interpolated.

Comment: By setting the emulator to max size, the color change goes away. But... I'm not sure what to do with this information, because I had to make the emulator bigger than what the actual phone would be for it to work. So... we are on the right track, its definitely being scaled funny, but how to stop it?